# Pygame Movie no sound every other time playing

Tags: python, audio, video, pygame, movie

I have a problem with the sound from pygame videos in a python script

before the loop i initalize it like that:

```
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.quit()
```

in a while loop sensors can trigger a video playing like that:

```
pygame.display.init()               
movie = pygame.movie.Movie(path)
if movie.has_video():
   screen = pygame.display.set_mode(movie.get_size())
   pygame.display.update()

   movie.set_display(screen)
   movie.set_volume(0.99)

   movie.play()

   while movie.get_busy():
         time.sleep(.100)

   pygame.display.quit()
```

the first time a movie plays, sound is available. The second time there is no sound, the third time sound is working fine again ... and so on.

if i check after pygame.display.init with pygame.mixer.get_init if the mixer is initialized it returns false.

also if i put the pygame.mixer.quit() inside the loop the video goes really slow (also without sound) and completly stops after a bit.

Comment: Why would you even do `pygame.mixer.quit()` since that removes the mixer functionality? _"pygame.mixer.quit - uninitialize the mixer"_ - Also, simply call `pygame.mixer.init()` right after `pygame.init()` to ensure that the mixer is loaded before you try to play any media? That way you know you've initialized the mixer and don't rely on some spooky behind-the-scenes magic.

Comment: It is important to quit the mixer in order for videos to be able to play sound.
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/movie.html

Comment: sounds strange but without testing i'll beleve this is in fact true. If so, move the `pygame.mixer.quit()` to right before movie.play() and see if that solves it? Maybe the initiliazation of pygame itself takes time and does things after you've called say `display.init()` which causes the mixer to become "alive" again.

Comment: as i wrote at the end of my question. If i do that, the second time i play a video it goes really slow with no sound and breaks after bit ...

Comment: What's the error message when it breaks? What sort of video are you trying to play? mkv?

Comment: it can only play .mpg videos, thats what the docu says. 
there is no error msg, at least python doesnt show one.

i found a workaround now ... but its not really nice:

after the while loop with time.sleep(.100) i add again:
movie = pygame.movie.Movie(path)

but this is not solving the problem, its just a workaround.

Comment: So my workaround is to play the video again for really short (you cant even see it). Its not perfect ... but working for now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe more a workaround than a answer:

The only way i got pygame.movie to keep playing sound when playing multiple movies is this:

- Before i create my first movie, i call `pygame.mixer.quit()`
- Whenever i want to play a new movie, i call the line `movie = pygame.movie.Movie('SOMEOTHERVIDEO.MPG')` 2 times.
- Its weird, but for me its the only way i got it working. This is on win7 / python3
- I find it especially weird that this workaround stops working if i remove the `movie=` from the first of the 2 calls to `pygame.movie.Movie('SOMENEWVIDEO.MPG')`.

Anyway here is some code that works for me:

```
import pygame

FPS = 60

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.mixer.quit()
movie = pygame.movie.Movie('SOMEVIDEO.mpg')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(movie.get_size())
movie_screen = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size()).convert()

movie.set_display(movie_screen)
movie.play()

cnt = 0
playing = True
while playing:
    cnt+=1
    if cnt>=500:
        cnt=0
        movie.stop()
        movie = pygame.movie.Movie('SOMEOTHERVIDEO.mpg')
        movie = pygame.movie.Movie('SOMEOTHERVIDEO.mpg')
        movie_screen = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size()).convert()
        movie.set_display(movie_screen)
        movie.play()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            movie.stop()
            playing = False
    screen.blit(movie_screen,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```